# Right mimeType for opening file

Tags: android, file, android-intent, mime-types

I'm trying to open a `File` with an `Intent`, but Android doesn't open the right application for the filetype.

Using the following code, every file - pdf, images, everything - is opened with the music app:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
startActivity(i);
```

When I manually specify the mimeType, the right application is opened - in this case the pictureviewer.

```
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
```

Is there any way to get Android to open the right application, instead of manually setting the type judging from the file's extension?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.setType(FileHelper.getMimeType(file));
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is (the relevant part of) my helper class **to get mimeType from file**.

The key is to use [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html)

```
public class FileHelper
{

    public static String getMimeType(File file)
    {
        return getMimeType(file.getName());
    }

    public static String getMimeType(String fileName)
    {
        String extension = getExtension(fileName);
        if (extension == null)
            return null;
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }

    public static String getExtension(File file)
    {
        return getExtension(file.getName());
    }

    public static String getExtension(String fileName)
    {
        int extensionDelimiter = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (extensionDelimiter == -1)
            return null;
        return fileName.substring(extensionDelimiter + 1, fileName.length());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

I wonder why SO moderators don't have the privilege to mark a response as an answer? MSDN Q/A site has this nice feature.

Comment: I just noticed that this sometimes doesn't work, like with png images. On the good side, I found the 2nd method in the following link working fine with all file types I tried.
http://helloworldcodes.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-open-folder-with-default.html

Comment: Doesn't work with png, really? On my side it's working. Thanks for the additional link :-)

Comment: that's strange. The image is blank when I open. Also, when I opened the .txt file using this, it can't open the file saying "File Open Error. Error during file opening."

Comment: I checked this with the Gallery app (opening the png with Gallery app) and it just opens my library. Doesn't open the file. :|

Comment: Did you check if your file is readable/not private to your app?

Comment: yes I can confirm since the other method I used works fine (the blogpost I linked to earlier). :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll dig that :-)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the other applications. If they have set their intent filters including mime information, file extension information or both. So, my recommendation is you can't rely on other applications, so the best option is to provide as much info as possible when you launch an intent, including MIME type.

Comment: But why can't Android figure the correct type on it's own? The intent reference states for the type "Specifies an explicit type (a MIME type) of the intent data. Normally the type is inferred from the data itself. By setting this attribute, you disable that evaluation and force an explicit type." This doesn't work at all with my code, so it has to be a mistake in it?